# Using Bash Regular Expressions to replace part of matched results

Tags: regex, bash

I have a file with lines that appear as:

1/foo/bar/

2/foo/bar/

3/foo/bar/

I would like to take two inputs, the first of which to match to the number. This is relatively simple. Then, I'd like to replace 'bar' with whatever is input for the second argument. Is this possible?

Comment: `bash` is Turing-complete, so yes, it's possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you edit your question to give an example of the sample output?  It is not entirely clear to me right now.

Answer (score 0):

This smells like a homework assignment, but anyway, if you're on Linux (bash) "sed" should be available to match a line and do a replacement in that line, otherwise passing through non-matching lines unchanged.